# html image not showing up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show some image on the background of a box but mine the image is not showing up
This is my html code for the selected section:

```
<a href="rot1">Vision</a>
<div style="display:none;">
<!--<div style="background-image: url(../img/slide1/background1.png); height: 200px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>-->
<div class="info_image">img/slide1/background1.png</div>
<div class="info_heading">Our Vision</div>
<div class="info_description">
    Create ICT as a driver to knowledge-based socioeconomic transformation initiatives.
<!--<a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>-->
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
img.bg{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Comment: Somehow I can't understand the `html` structure.

Comment: Why do you have the div with the background image commented out?

Comment: @PatrickAllen this is what i am trying to do actually http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PrettySimpleContentSlider/#
http://jsfiddle.net/Wt869/

Comment: @JunM sorry i have shortened the code... well this is the full code http://jsfiddle.net/Wt869/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a couple of things out of whack here. Your CSS is pointing to an image tag and class that do not exist and a containing(?) div that is set to `display:none;`. Consider the following

```
<a href="rot1">Vision</a>
<div class="info_image">
  <div class="info_heading">Our Vision</div>
  <div class="info_description">
    Create ICT as a driver to knowledge-based socioeconomic transformation initiatives.
  <!--<a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>-->
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.info_image {
  background-image: url('../img/slide1/background1.png'); 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

If you want the image to show up above the description, using an actual image tag will work. Try the following.

```
<a href="rot1">Vision</a>
<div class="info_image"><img src="../img/slide1/background1.png" /></div>
<div class="info_heading">Our Vision</div>
<div class="info_description">
    Create ICT as a driver to knowledge-based socioeconomic transformation initiatives.
  <!--<a href="#" class="more">Read more</a>-->
</div>
```

Comment: but there is 1 problem after changing this the image shows up but too small and the descriptions shows in the image

Comment: Edited the post to include an example with the image showing up above the description. If that's the desired affect, you can remove the CSS `background-image` :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going on with the class you're referencing in that div tag but I believe you only need to read the following to get what you want.

http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0301/0301-CSS-DIV-BACKGROUND-IMAGE.html

Comment: I have tried this yesterday but it still doesnt work for my case

Answer (score 0):

In the [plugin you're using](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PrettySimpleContentSlider/#) The div with class `info_image` holds the image url.

If `../img/slide1/background1.png` is the image url, you need to put:

`<div class="info_image">../img/slide1/background1.png</div>`

and not:

`<div class="info_image">img/slide1/background1.png</div>`

as you did.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="info_image">img/slide1/background1.png</div>
```

try this instead of above

```
<div class="info_image"><img src="img/slide1/background1.png"></div>
```